# Objects appear as black in material preview mode and when rendering

Tags: materials

I have been rendering this file for a while now and no problems occurred so I decided to work on other things while the file was rendering. However, when I went to check up on it, it appears black. I'm new to blender so I don't fully understand it yet.
This problem suddenly happened and only happens in material preview mode and the preview when rendering.

Material Preview
[image]

Render Preview
[image]

Comment: In Material Preview, what are the settings of the Viewport Shading panel (top right of the 3D view, next to the 4 preview modes)? If you've enabled the Scene World option and disable the Scene Lights option, you won't have any light...

Comment: Neither Scene World or Scene Lights options were enabled

Comment: could you please share your file (just several objects) so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've uploaded it to the link you sent me
Here's the link incase you need it: [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/b51a30620cea4ed5ae8ed9eabf127fbe)

Comment: it seems to work here (except you haven't packed your images but I don't think it counts), so I'm not sure what's happening: https://zupimages.net/up/22/16/gs6z.jpg

Comment: Sorry I'm being stupid, I reloaded Blender and it works now. Thanks

Comment: oh, great then  ;)  .......